# How-to preselect value in PHP dropdown list from LINK

Tags: php

I'd like to modify my code so that a user clicks on one of several links, and they see a contact form with a corresponding item in a drop-down list preselected.

Example:

1. On an automotive website (ie: BMW) they generally have many model pages.
2. Select Model > 128I Coupe and on this page you can click a button to 'Request Test Drive',
3. From there it will direct you to the test-drive form.
4. In this case, I would like 128i Coupe be pre-selected in the model drop-down list.

The form is complete but this would make it easier to use.

This is just a snip of what code I have currently:

```
    <label>Vehicle Model, Option 1:</label>                 
    <select type="select" name="model_select1" id="model_select1" class="requiredField model_select1">
    <option>Select One</option>
    <option value="111">128i Cabriolet</option>
    <option value="222">128i Coupé</option>
    <option value="333">135i Cabriolet</option>
    <option value="444">135i Coupé</option>
    </select>
```

I would also require how to properly write the link from the previous page. Would something like `mywebsite.com/1series.html?model_select1=1201` work?

Comment: Please read the PHP manual, especially this basic section: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php - If you don't know what a URI/URL or HTTP Request is, the technical basics are exaplained next to Wikipedia in so called RFC documents you can find via Google. But reading the PHP manual page carefully should already enable you to solve your concrete problem.

Comment: I've trimmed the question down a bit - try to make your posts as succinct as you can! The answer is in your last paragraph; yes, just add a _query string_ to the link, so that when you get to your contact form, it can be read from the `$_GET` array. I would imagine that you wouldn't link to the name of the vehicle (1series.html) unless you're using URL rewriting; instead you'd use the name of the contact form (mywebsite.com/testdrive.php?model_select=1series) and get the model name from `$_GET`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is for each select option check if the parameter model_select1 is the same value as the actual select:

```
<?php $model = $_GET["model_select1"] ?>    
<label>Vehicle Model, Option 1:</label>                 
    <select type="select" name="model_select1" id="model_select1" class="requiredField model_select1">
    <option>Select One</option>
    <option value="111" <?=($model == "111")? "selected='selected'" : "" ?>>128i Cabriolet</option>
    <option value="222" <?=($model == "222")? "selected='selected'" : "" ?>>128i Coupé</option>
    <option value="333" <?=($model == "333")? "selected='selected'" : "" ?>>135i Cabriolet</option>
    <option value="444" <?=($model == "444")? "selected='selected'" : "" ?>>135i Coupé</option>
    </select>
```

You would also have to rename your file from `.com/1series.html?model_select1=1201` to `.com/1series.php?model_select1=1201` in order to accept PHP code inside.

Comment: Such great help, I really appreciate it! 
I tested your code this morning and had received a syntax error but by removing the quotations around the "selected" everything worked great.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry about that, just realized that I used 2 double quotes, fixed it. Please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

To make an option the default, just add `selected` to the tag. e.g., `<option selected value="111">`

You can use the query string in the link to indicate which option should be selected, and get that value from the `$_GET` array. Then use conditionals to determine which option to add the `selected` property to.